# how to generate a excel report of the customers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

OP asks how an excel report can be generated for customers based on this code:

```py
class customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    

class info(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    

class detail(models.Model):
    proof = models.ForeignKey(customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    aadhar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100,default=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Tablib to do it. https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.
There is actually a django package as well : https://github.com/joshourisman/django-tablib

Example:

```
data = tablib.Dataset(headers=['name'])
for d in customer.objects.values('name'):
    data.append(name)
data.export('xlsx') # this will output the excel file
```

And you can use `django.http.FileResponse()` class to send it back to the user from the view.